# Spring Boot with OAuth 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm using Spring Boot to create my microservices and I'm enabling the OAuth2 to add security to my services.

However, there are some methods that I can not understand what are the differences between then. For example, I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(POST, "/v1/files/").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')");
}
```

In this example, I used the **access** method to check if the system that is going to access my services has the ROLE_CLIENT role.

The question is : **what are the main differences between the following methods**:

- hasRole
- hasAuthority
- access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasRole(NAME)` checks that client has `ROLE_NAME` whether `hasAuthority(NAME)` checks only `NAME` role.

Answer (score 0):

hasRole("CLIENT") is equivalent to hasAuthority("ROLE_CLIENT")